# laravel vue products inside categories

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pagination, axios

how can i put a pagination that shows 5 products in every category using laravel backend and vue frontend?

```
<!-- this generates the categories -->
<template v-for="category in categories" v-if="category.MENUID === menu.MENUID">
<div class="categoryName">
<span class="float-left">
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left bh" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" :href="'#'+category.CATNAME" role="button" :data-target="'#'+category.CATNAME" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="'collapseOne-'+category.UID" @click.once.prevent="getProductsOf(category.CATID)">
<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> {{category.CATNAME}}
    </button>
</span>
```

```
    <!-- this generates 5 products and pagination for all products in the category -->
    <template v-for="product in catProducts.data" v-if="product.CATID === category.CATID">
        <div class="productName">{{product.PRODNAME}}</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

the laravel part works OK, but Vue keeps generation a new pagination for all categories everytime it has to generate it for a single one.

```
getProductsOf(catid) {
            this.$Progress.start();
            axios.get('/api/getproducts/'+this.compid+'/'+catid)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.catProducts = data.data.products;
                })
                .catch(() => {

                });
            this.$Progress.finish();
        },
```

and this is the axios that is sent to Laravel to get the data. Data received is correct but the pagination buttons don't work and everytime i open a new category all category paginations get replaced with the new category i click on.

Comment: What does the `data` section of your Vue instance look like? You have a single `catProducts` array that is overwritten whenever you make the `axios` call.

Comment: the data is an array of products, each product has a name, price, description and so on. the problem i'm facing is that is simply want to make a pagination for every category. But the problem is that if i open category 1 i see 3 pagination links for example, then i open the 2nd category and i see 2 pagination link and the first category will become 2 pagination links too. it's giving same pagination for all categories.

Comment: data() {
            return {
                editmode: false,
                restid: this.$route.params.restid,
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                restaurant: [],
                menus: [],
                categories: [],
                catProducts: {},
                products: {
                    UID: '',
                    CATID: '',
                    DESCRIPT: '',
                    PRICE: '',
                    TAG1: '',
                    TAG2: '',
                },
        }
},